# How to retrieve JWT Access Token from HTTP Cookie using req.cookies in Passport.JS?

Tags: reactjs, express, passport.js

I've been trying to get hold of the access tokens using passport but with some of the strategies it doesn't work, besides GitHub strategy, which can retrieve the tokens.

This one returns both accessToken and refreshToken:

```
passport.use(
  new GitHubStrategy(
    {
      clientID: process.env.GITHUB_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL: process.env.GITHUB_CALLBACK,
      passReqToCallback: true,
    },
    async (req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
      console.log('GitHub Profile:', profile);

      console.log('github', req.cookies);
      return;
    }
  )
);
```

But Microsoft would return req.cookies undefined using the same strategy code:

```
passport.use(
  new MicrosoftStrategy(
    {
      clientID: process.env.MICROSOFT_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.MICROSOFT_CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL: process.env.MICROSOFT_CALLBACK,
      scope: ['user.read'],
      tenant: 'common',
      userAudience: 'All',
      authorizationURL:
        'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize',
      tokenURL: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token',
      passReqToCallback: true,
    },
    async (req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
      console.log('Microsoft Profile', profile);

      console.log('microsoft', req.cookies);
      return;
    }
  )
);
```

Here's a GitHub link to the redirect links I am using for each provider on client side: https://github.com/AndreiNPaun/passport-auth/blob/94efe216c82f140e72eeb9c50d38ee5a7cf973d2/client/src/utils/authorizationLinks.js

I have tried enabling passReqToCallback to all providers but still only GitHub seems to work. There is a chance the oauth flow on GitHub strategy differs from the others which would enable it to get access to the stored cookies.